# how to fix this npm start not working ( after npx create-react-app )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, command

> ```
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! todos-clone-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the todos-clone-app@0.1.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/josh/.npm/_logs/2020-08-21T19_28_35_521Z-debug.log
> ```

**Edit:**

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "todos-clone-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [ ">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all" ],
    "development": [ "last 1 chrome version", "last 1 firefox version", "last 1 safari version" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try deleting your `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` file. Then run `npm install`.

Comment: share the latest log from `/home/josh/.npm/_logs/ ` directory

Comment: /home/josh/.npm/_logs/2020-08-21T20_00_59_578Z-debug.log this one?

Comment: yes, if this is the latest one. You can find the latest file in a directory using `ls -lhrt` in unix. The last file on the list is the latest one.

Comment: total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 josh josh 512 Aug 21 13:04

Comment: `cd /home/josh/.npm/_logs/`
`ls -lhrt`
open the last file using vi or less
copy everything inside the file and paste it here.

if the contents are large in numbers, delete the file, run `npm start`, wait till you get the error, then follow the above instructions.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was because of not being in the right folder.

Generally, I create a folder and go to Vs code to open it for typing `create-react-app "folder name"` to the console.

The problem was I was trying to `npm start` in parent folder instead of "folder name".

All you have to do is:

1. `cd folder_name`
2. `npm start`

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
npx create-react-app ./
```

It worked for me.