# i run npx create-react-app and npm start command not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

> ```
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
> npm ERR! syscall open
> npm ERR! path /mnt/c/Users/x/package.json
> npm ERR! errno -2
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/c/Users/x/package.json'
> npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
> npm ERR! enoent
>      
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! /home/josh/.npm/_logs/2020-08-21T20_00_59_578Z-debug.log
> ```

```json
{
  "name": "todos-clone-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this much different than your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63516613/how-to-fix-this-npm-start-not-working-after-npx-create-react-app?

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: it same but didnt work

Comment: Are you in the root directory of the app?

Comment: You marked the answer as accepted in the other one though. If this is the same issue and the other question isn't resolved then please update that question with the newer, more relevant details.